# IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/' while copying files from one folder to another existing folder Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a basic file manager to practice. I've ran into trouble while trying to copy files from a directory, into another already existing directory.

```
def singulateDataInDir(SRCdir, passBackFiles=bool, passBackDirs=bool):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SRCdir, topdown=True):
        for name in files:
            filesInSRCdir = os.path.join(root, name)
            if passBackFiles is True:
                return filesInSRCdir
        for name in dirs:
            dirsInSRCdir = os.path.join(root, name)
            if passBackDirs is True:
                return dirsInSRCdir

def copyFilesFromSRCtoDEST(SRCdir, DESTdir):  
    for files in singulateDataInDir(SRCdir, True, False):
        shutil.copy2(files, DESTdir)
```

I attempt to sort through items in the SRCdir and depending on the parameters it returns files, directories, or both.
I get an error saying my destination is a directory (I think? perhaps the '/' means that I'm typing the code incorrectly.)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    main(True)
  File "main.py", line 38, in main
    code.copyFilesFromSRCtoDEST(srcOpt, destOpt)
  File "/Users/jcrd/Documents/csProjects/pythonProjects/screenshotCollecting/code.py", line 34, in copyFilesFromSRCtoDEST
    shutil.copy2(files, DESTdir)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 432, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'
```

Any help would be amazing, thank you for looking at my question.

Comment: are you using windows or linux

Comment: Please print `files` and `DESTdir` before copying!

Comment: @rcvaram im on Mac

Comment: @KlausD. I added a print and I got `/Users/jcrd/Documents/pics2/.DS_Store` which really has me confused now because the only thing in that folder im copying is a Minecraft screenshot

Comment: Files and folder starting with a period are hidden in many GUI file managers. Try `ls -al`!

Comment: any tips on what I can do to solve my issue? @KlausD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `singulateDataInDir` does not yield filenames and is not a generator. It returns a single path with `return filesInSRCdir` and so

```
for files in singulateDataInDir(SRCdir, True, False):
```

iterates the characters in the name returned, starting with the leading forward slash "/". Thus the error `Is a directory: '/'`. Te fix is to `yield` instead of `return`. You also need to fiddle with the default parameters to the function. `bool` is a type object, it doesn't mean that input has to be a bool.

```
def singulateDataInDir(SRCdir, passBackFiles=False, passBackDirs=False):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SRCdir, topdown=True):
        for name in files:
            filesInSRCdir = os.path.join(root, name)
            if passBackFiles is True:
                yield filesInSRCdir
        for name in dirs:
            dirsInSRCdir = os.path.join(root, name)
            if passBackDirs is True:
                yield dirsInSRCdir

def copyFilesFromSRCtoDEST(SRCdir, DESTdir):  
    for files in singulateDataInDir(SRCdir, True, False):
        shutil.copy2(files, DESTdir)
```